# In the CMIS TCK unit tests, what "INFO" actually mean "passed"?

Tags: unit-testing, cmis, apache-chemistry, cmis-workbench

I am trying to [score the results of the CMIS TCK unit tests for each ECM server](http://cmissync.org/CmisCompat).
For the score, I just count the number of passed unit tests.

**PROBLEM**: Some "INFO" sound very much like they actually mean "passed".
**QUESTION**: Is there a way to know what "INFO" lines actually mean that the test passed?

---

Example ([full](http://cmissync.org/CmisCompat/nemakiware-live-demo-20140718.html)):

```
Checks the root folder and its children for specification compliance.
  OK: Root folder id: /

Checks all types exposed by the repository for specification compliance.
  INFO: Checked 19 type definitions.

Creates a document type and deletes it again.
  INFO: Created type 'tck:testid_without_properties'.
  INFO: Created type 'tck:testid_with_properties'.
```

Explanation of the example:

- "*Root folder id: /*" succeeds and is rendered as "OK", perfect.
- "*Checked 19 type definitions*" succeeds but is rendered as "INFO", not "OK".
- Same for the 2 others.

On the contrary, some other "INFO"s appear to be purely informative:

```
  INFO: Binding: ATOMPUB
```

For a particular server, the number of INFO was 2635, which is much more than the number of tests.